# Powershell script error with apostrophes

Tags: powershell

This isn't my code, and I really don't understand powershell very much, but I have a script here for getting access to files (or something). There's an error with special characters like apostrophes, and I know about escape sequences, but I'm parsing through a folder and for each folder (and later file) I'm using setaccesscontrol on each folder/file. I can't use escape sequences for each one since it's stored in the $fol variable, and it will be different each loop. I'm a total novice and don't get powershell at all, but I do get java so I'm basing my understanding on that. Any help is appreciated.

```
foreach($Fol in $Folder2){
$fol = $fol.fullname
$NewOwnerACL = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSecurity
$Admin = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($WhoIsNewOwner)
write-host ...$Admin to $Fol -Fore Yellow
$NewOwnerACL.SetOwner($Admin)
[System.IO.File]::SetAccessControl($fol, $NewOwnerACL)}
```

The error is:

Exception calling "SetAccessControl" with "2" argument(s):
"C:\shares\Operations...something with apostrophe"

At C:\cp\PermissionFixer.ps1:28 char:5

+     [System.IO.File]::SetAccessControl($fol, $NewOwnerACL)

+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

+ CategoryInfo              :NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException

+ CategoryInfo              :FileNotFoundException

Edit: I found that those long dashes screwed it up. I'm using robocopy on this script to get past the 255 or whatever world limit, and I think it may be reading the long dashes incorrectly? Is there any way around this other than just parsing through each string looking for it?

Comment: You shouldn't need escape sequences - no string parsing involved. What is the _full_ error message you're getting?

Comment: `static void SetAccessControl(string path, System.Security.AccessControl.FileSecurity fileSecurity)`..did you check that the $fol path exist?

Comment: @Hackerman I did, and I'm pretty sure it's there. I think it gets $fol from parsing through this folder, so I'm not sure how that would mess up. The other folders and files totally work, except this one. Only thing I noticed was the (').

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need escape sequences, because there is no string parsing involved.

[Hackerman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1987838/hackerman) provides what I believe to be the crucial pointer in a comment on the question: **`$fol` may simply point to a *nonexistent path*.**

This is also supported by the `CategoryInfo` value contained in the error message you're reporting: `FileNotFoundException`.

As for a reference to "apostrophe": my best guess is that the path contained in `$fol` may actually literally contain that word.

Apostrophes (`'`) are legal NTFS filename characters, so they shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: "so they shouldn't be a problem." This is weirdly not the case, at least when using the Shift+Right Click method of opening a Powershell window in a directory. It produces the error "The string is missing the terminator: '." when performing that action in a folder with an apostrophe in the name.

Comment: @JAB: That's good to know, but it is simply a bug in that shell-integration feature, not an NTFS or PowerShell problem: the command underlying this feature incorrectly assumes that a `'` won't ever be embedded in folder names - see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1310259/139307) of mine at superuser.com for a fix.